# Hidden form submit with model as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to figure out how to send the `MVC` `Model` to my `ActionResult` method, but the data on the `AccountsManagementDetailsModel model` is always empty or `null`, even though the **model object** itself is properly constructed, only with **empty properties**.

My method on the **controller**:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(AccountsManagementDetailsModel model)
    {
        ...
    }
```

My **JQuery**:

```
    var form = $('<form action="@Url.Action("ResetPassword", "AccountsManagement")" method="POST">');

    var input = $("<input>")
           .attr("type", "hidden")
           .attr("name", "model").val(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));

    form.append(input + "</input></form>");
    form.appendTo('body').submit();
```

My `AccountsManagementDetailsModel`:

```
public class AccountsManagementDetailsModel : UserInfo
{
    public bool New { get; set; }
}

public class UserInfo
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool Customer { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public bool MustChangePassword { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't understand how MVC binding works. Basically in your case you send string `model` with your serialized model to your controller.

Comment: Well. Thanks for pointing the obvious.

Comment: Please post your model code, I think the problem is that you have you have an input per value in the model. i.e. AccountsManagementDetailsModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to sent your model is create inputs for each property of your model. It could be difficult but you can use [EditorTemplate](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm) that generate you html with assistance of `HtmlHelpers`.

The easiest way that i can see is to change your code like this:

```
  var form = $('<form action="@Url.Action("ResetPassword", "AccountsManagement")" method="POST">' + formHtml + "</form>");

var formHtml = '@Html.Raw(Html.EditorForModel().ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br />"))';

form.append(formHtml  + "</form>");
form.appendTo('body').submit();
```

Helper `EditorForModel` should create valid inputs (with right `name` attributes) for you and allow you to post model to controller and bind it there.

Anyway if you don't want to change your code this way you can change your controller code like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(string model)
{
    AccountsManagementDetailsModel modelBind = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<AccountsManagementDetailsModel>(model);
}
```

This lines should deserialize your serialized `string` from Json to your model.

Comment: Javascript error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
       `var formHtml = '<div class="editor-label"><label for="New">New</label></div>`

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino i gess it's my bad. Looks like you can't just add this kind of string to your model that simple. Result Html from `EditorForModel` too tricky for js.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino i will think how to help you. Other way will not help you too?

Comment: Have not tried yet. I'm more interested in getting the first one working rather than the second. So I'll keep trying the first for a while.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino you definatly can do it this way: `<input type="hidden" name="UserName" value="@Model.UserName" />` for each of your properties. But i think you searching for general way.

Comment: Got it working your way:
`var formHtml = '@Html.Raw(Html.EditorForModel().ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br />"))';

        var form = $('<form action="@Url.Action("ResetPassword", "AccountsManagement")" method="POST">' +
            formHtml + "</form>");`

Comment: Please update your question with my fix and I'll accept it.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino i do as you say :)